# Is it possible to restrict accessing webpages within specific region

Tags: vpn, internet, browser, proxy, website

I am trying to access a website that is located outside USA, in Asia specifically. My family there said they are able to access it while I cannot do so from United States. Does that mean webpages could be associated with specific geographic areas? I have never thought about that. If so, is there a way to access this webpage that seems to be restricted to that region?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible for a site to block access based on region. And there are a lot of sites that do it for one reason or another.

If that is the case (which obviously isn't sure, there might be different reasons for you not being able to access that site) to bypass that you'd need a VPN service that allows you to choose that specific region it is open in.

Answer (score 0):

**Blocking by country**

Yes, websites can be blocked by country.

See ["how to block countries from accessing your website"](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-block-entire-countries-from-accessing-website/) for more details.

One example is that you might think one country is a source of hackers, and you don't want to have them trying to log in to your site. Or maybe a shopping site doesn't want to ship to the other side of the world.

**How to fix it**

You need to make the website think you are in their country, or a country they like.

Best option is a VPN located in that country. You could try [VPN Asia](https://vpn.asia/). I've never used them, but they have servers in several Asian countries. If you pay them money and follow their set up instructions, you should be able to make it appear that your computer is located in in Hong Kong/Malaysia/Singapore/Vietnam etc.

If you don't want to pay money, but you are tech savvy, you may be able to get one of your relatives to set up access through their computer, if they leave it turned on. Check out [Liefehacker: how-to-build-your-own-vpn](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/04/how-to-build-your-own-vpn/).